# How to handle Tokenized text content which is given in number?

Tags: machine-learning, pandas, nlp

i have one data set of customer review, but the text data is given is tokenized text number. I am unable to proceed thinking about how to proceed?

As I am encountering such data set the first time, so just need guide how to proceed.

[image]

As you can see text field is given in number, so how to proceed please guide?. it will predict the 0/1 +ve or -ve category.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in general case, machines do not understand the text, but they understand the numbers. Thus, we always tokenize the text followed by converting them to some form of numbers. We build a vocabulary of words from the given document, where each word can be assumed as a number corresponding to its index in the vocabulary. Further, this number is converted to one-hot vector representations.

Since, you already have sequence of numbers instead of words, you can make an assumption that you can convert them directly to it's one-hot vectors. Or in a advanced way, you can use a embedding layer to learn the embeddings (especially if you are using the neural networks.)